# Como inserir um evento no item de menu do Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android

Como inserir um evento no item de menu do Navigation Drawer? Só consegui fazer utilizando os menus de opção sem ser do Nav. Drawer.

LoginActivity.java

```
package com.androidbegin.parselogintutorial;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import br.isckosta.sharingfuel.adapter.ListViewAdapter;
import br.isckosta.sharingfuel.model.Posto;

import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseFile;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.PushService;

public class FeedActivityNavigationDrawer extends Activity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mPlanetTitles;

ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
private List<Posto> posto = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this,
            FeedActivityNavigationDrawer.class);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
    mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
    R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
    R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
    R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_websearch:

        return true;
    case R.id.add_new_post:

        return true;
    case R.id.sair:

        ParseUser.logOut();
        finish();

        Intent i = new Intent(FeedActivityNavigationDrawer.this,
                LoginSignupActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(
                FeedActivityNavigationDrawer.this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Carregando novos preços");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Atualizando...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        posto = new ArrayList<Posto>();
        try {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                    "Posto");
            query.orderByAscending("ranknum");
            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject country : ob) {
                ParseFile image = (ParseFile) country.get("flag");

                Posto map = new Posto();
                map.setNome((String) country.get("nome"));
                map.setBandeira((String) country.get("bandeira"));
                map.setEndereco((String) country.get("endereco"));
                map.setFlag(image.getUrl());
                posto.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(FeedActivityNavigationDrawer.this,
                posto);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

    public PlanetFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet,
                container, false);
        int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
        String planet = getResources()
                .getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

        int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(
                planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()), "drawable",
                getActivity().getPackageName());
        ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image))
                .setImageResource(imageId);
        getActivity().setTitle(planet);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

Eu inseri esse código no selectedItem() porém ele sempre executa um destes casos quando abre a activity

```
  switch (position) {

    case 0:

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        break;


    case 1:

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Criar novo preço", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        break;

    case 2:

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sobre",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case 3:

        ParseUser.logOut();
        finish();

        Intent i = new Intent(FeedActivityNavigationDrawer.this,
                LoginSignupActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Pelo seu código, você está abrindo somente o `PlanetFragment` passando o item selecionado em questão. Tudo acontece no seu método `selectItem()`. O que exatamente ou qual evento você pretende fazer?

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta @PauloRodrigues

Answer (score 2):

Você deve implementar o listener do drawer, inserindo o córigo abaixo:

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

/** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
private void selectItem(int position) {
    // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on position
    Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                   .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                   .commit();

    // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

Comment: Como fazer no caso do evento sem abrir um fragment? Tipo tem um botão de Logout.

Comment: No método selectItem(), se a posição selecionada for a opção de Logout, aí você faz uma chamada pra função de fazer Logout.

Comment: Eu fiz utilizando o switch olha na pergunta.

Comment: Eu consegui fazer, porém agora sempre que abre a activity o primeiro menu Home é executado.

Comment: Talvez a opção de home esteja na posição 0

Comment: Eu vi antes de você postar seu comentário rsrs... Muito obrigado @Daniel Reis

Answer (score 0):

Agora que eu vi pessoal, no método onCreate() está sendo chamada o método

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
}
```

No qual já cria a Activity selecionando a primeira posição, faltou eu observar isso. 
Obrigado a ajuda de todos.

Eu tenho que deixar, pois sempre que a Activity é aberta, ela irá chamar a primeira posição que significa a posição do primeiro fragment que é o Feed.